# Where does MFC get the Automation IDs from?

Tags: c++, user-interface, automation, mfc

I am about to add automatic GUI tests to an MFC application (created with Visual Studio 2019). It seems as AutomationId is something that could be useful when identifying various child windows in the application.

When I examined the application using Microsoft’s tool “Visual UIA Verify” I noticed that most of the child windows in the application have AutomationIds.

My concern is that they might not be unique if I have multiple instances of a window class and that the IDs may change over time.

My questions are

- Where do the AutomationIds come from?
- Can I change them?
- Can I rely on them being constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation IDs are obtained from UIA (User Interface Accessibility), you should generally be able to count on them being the same from run-to-run of the same program, but note that a new version may or may not be "the same".

From the UIA documentation:

> Identifies the AutomationId       property, which is a string containing the UI Automation identifier (ID) for the automation element.
> When it is available, the AutomationId       of an element must be the same in any instance of the application, regardless of the local language. The value should be unique among sibling elements, but not necessarily unique across the entire desktop. For example, multiple instances of an application, or multiple folder views in Microsoft Windows Explorer, can contain elements with the same AutomationId       property, such as "SystemMenuBar".
> Although support for AutomationId       is always recommended for better automated testing support, this property is not mandatory. Where it is supported, AutomationId       is useful for creating a test automation script that runs regardless of the UI language. Clients should make no assumptions regarding the AutomationId       values exposed by other applications. AutomationId       is not guaranteed to be stable across different releases or builds of an application.

Comment: So, one important point is that they should be the same regardless of language settings and on which computer it is run on. That is good. A remaining problem is if I have, say, two instances of a class derived from CView. Can I use the AutomationId to pick the right instance? Is there any way I can control or figure out which AutomationId is being used for the different instances.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the automation id is just the control id for the window's child control.

This is automatically set for controls in dialogs loaded from a resource (.rc file). The control id can also be set at runtime for non-dialog controls by passing a number for the `HMENU` parameter in [CreateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa).  So yes, you can typically assume the control IDs are static.

Comment: I doubt that's accurate. Take a regular popup menu, where each entry has a different AutomationId, even though there are neither child windows nor child window IDs.

Comment: It appears to be right for the controls in dialogs at least, which is good.